# How to remove element array properly in godot

Tags: godot

Hello im working on random placement for units on my game but i'm getting a very strange behaviour that could not understand, sometimes the array element removed from the array befor on the loop get removed again even that elelement not been show on the array. Could someone plz explaim me.

```
func update_avaliable_positions(pos):
     #remover posição  das disponiveis
     var mob_pos = tilemap.world_to_map(pos)
     var index = avaliable_positions.find(mob_pos)
     #avaliable_positions.erase(mob_pos)
     avaliable_positions.remove(index)
     print('erase: ', mob_pos)
     walkable_map.set_cellv(mob_pos, -1)



func populate(total):
   randomize()
   for n in range(total):
       print('mob: ', n)
       print('avaliable: ', avaliable_positions)
       var rand_pos = randi() % avaliable_positions.size() #walkable_map.get_used_cells().size()
       var mob = MonsterDatabase.add_mob('orc')
       mob.position = tilemap.map_to_world(walkable_map.avaliable_cells[rand_pos]) + tilemap.cell_size/2
       mobs_list.add_child(mob)
       update_avaliable_positions(mob.position - tilemap.cell_size/2)
       yield(get_tree().create_timer(3), "timeout" )
```

the out put is this:

player

avaliable: [(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (12, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4), (15, 4), (2, 5), (13, 5), (2, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (8, 7), (9, 7), (10, 7), (11, 7), (12, 7), (13, 7), (14, 7), (15, 7)]

erase: (15, 4)

mob: 0

avaliable: [(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (12, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4), (2, 5), (13, 5), (2, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (8, 7), (9, 7), (10, 7), (11, 7), (12, 7), (13, 7), (14, 7), (15, 7)]

erase: (13, 7)

mob: 1

avaliable: [(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (12, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4), (2, 5), (13, 5), (2, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (8, 7), (9, 7), (10, 7), (11, 7), (12, 7), (14, 7), (15, 7)]

erase: (9, 7)

mob: 2

avaliable: [(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (12, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4), (2, 5), (13, 5), (2, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (8, 7), (10, 7), (11, 7), (12, 7), (14, 7), (15, 7)]

erase: (15, 4) ---> here we see that (15,4) dont exist between options before

mob: 3

avaliable: [(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (12, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4), (2, 5), (13, 5), (2, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (8, 7), (10, 7), (11, 7), (12, 7), (14, 7), (15, 7)]

erase: (2, 7)

mob: 4

avaliable: [(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (12, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4), (2, 5), (13, 5), (2, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7), (8, 7), (10, 7), (11, 7), (12, 7), (14, 7), (15, 7)]

erase: (2, 7) ---> here we see that (2,7) dont exist between options before

any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the array `walkable_map.avaliable_cells[rand_pos]` comes from but if it is not updated at the same time as the `avaliable_positions` array, it will return positions already removed.

Change your code by `mob.position = tilemap.map_to_world(avaliable_positions[rand_pos]) + tilemap.cell_size/2` and it should work.

I would also avoid conversion between map coordinates and world coordinates to retrieve elements in the `avaliable_positions` array. You should pass the `rand_pos` value directly when you call the `update_avaliable_positions` function so you don't have to look up again for the index of the element to remove.